# Amazon simple email service(SES) pricing for application hosted on lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-lightsail

I am using amazon lightsail for hosting my website. I would like to use simple email service for my website. SES have different price model for an application hosted on ec-2. Application hosted on lightsail falls under ec-2 pricing category?

Comment: This question should probably be asked in the Amazon Lightsail forum (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=231).

Answer (score 2):

> Application hosted on lightsail falls under ec-2 pricing category?

**NO**.

From https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=806414&#806414:

> We checked with the SES team and unfortunately, Lightsail does not
>   qualify for this free tier.